# How to create a table with all dates of year/s in ms access?

Tags: database, datetime, ms-access

I need to make a table where only one column will consists of all dates of year (ex. 2019 and 2020)

What is the good way to achieve that in MS Access 2010?

Answer (score 2):

You can create that list *dynamically*.

First, create a tiny query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM MSysObjects;
```

Save it as **Ten**.

Then use it in this *Cartesian* (multiplying) query:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    [Year] Short;
SELECT 
    DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),1,1+[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100) AS [Date]
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, 
    Ten AS Ten_1, 
    Ten AS Ten_2
WHERE 
    ([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100) <=
    DateDiff("d",DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),1,1),DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),12,31))
ORDER BY 
    DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),1,1+[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100);
```

It will return all dates for the passed year. If this is invalid, the dates of the *current year* is returned.

Comment: @Adriaan: There is no "every four year" here. It simply returns the dates of the (specified) year, this being a leap year or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a FOR loop in code to INSERT the values.